# The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered

Tags: sql-server, oledb, openrowset, aceoledb

I am trying to import an Excel file into SQL Server for that I decided to use
OPENROWSET.

I have done below steps:

Step 1:-

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Step2:-

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

Step3:-

```
Installed AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.Exe file.
```

Step4:-

```
SELECT* FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                       'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Share\c.xls;', 
                       'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Here I got ERROR like this

> "The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered."

But above all the steps executed without any error.

When I run this below query

```
Exec sp_MSset_oledb_prop
```

I can't find "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" in the list.
[image]
Server Configuration blow:
OS: Windows Server 2016 - 64bit
SQL: Sql Server 2017

The same way I have followed the above Steps working fine 2 different servers.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.Exe` did you install? 2012, 2016, a different one?

Comment: I have installed 2010

Comment: Are you facing this issue only in the server? Does the code work properly in local machine?

Comment: Yes, Working fine

Comment: Are you sureyou installed `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64` on the server? Having it on your local machine won't help the server the instance is installed on. Sounds like you installed or locally, and not remotely.

Comment: Yes, I have installed AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 On the server